# Terraform remote state configuration for modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Terraform v0.10.7

I am in a process of putting terraform modules together for our DevOps team. There will be separate modules for each component that we are using and in turn will create entire stack using those modules for different environments and requirements.

The directory hierarchy is as follows:

```
Terraform
  - modules
     - module-1 (main.tf, vars.tf, outputs.tf, backend.tf)
     - module-2 (main.tf, vars.tf, outputs.tf, backend.tf)
     - module-3 (main.tf, vars.tf, outputs.tf, backend.tf)
     ...
  - environments
     - qa (main.tf, vars.tf, outputs.tf, bakend.tf)
     - stage (main.tf, vars.tf, outputs.tf, bakend.tf)
     - prod (main.tf, vars.tf, outputs.tf, bakend.tf)
```

In **backend.tf** I have specified backend as S3 and a complete hierarchy as `/resources/mod-1/terraform.tfstate`. Same thing applies for backend.tf in environments.

When I give `terraform get` and `terraform apply` for any environment, it will fetch all the modules specified and will apply the changes to AWS infrastructure and it will store terraform.tfstate of that env at specified location in S3.

So the question is, will the *terraform.tfstate* for all the modules used in environment will also get generated and pushed to S3 (with single apply to env)?
I haven't ran `terraform apply` to any modules.

As I have a plan to use some data from *terraform.tfstate* of those modules from S3 and at the same time want to avoid giving multiple applies to those modules and give single `terraform apply` to environment. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think you need to re-write same `*.tf` files for each environment. So for each application, depend on which modules will be sourced, you should have below file structures:

```
Application-1
     - modules-1.tf
     - modules-2.tf
     - modules-3.tf
     - main.tf, vars.tf, outputs.tf
     - qa (qa/backend.conf, qa/qa.tfvars)
     - stag (stag/backend.conf, stag/stag.tfvars)
     - prod (prod/backend.conf, stag/prod.tfvars)
```

in /backend.conf, you can define the s3 backend (if you use aws)

```
bucket  = "<global_unique_bucket_name>"
key     = "<env>/network.tfstate"
region  = "us-east-1"
kms_key_id = "alias/terraform"
encrypt = true
```

Secondly, there should be no backend required for each module (if my understand is right, the backend is used to save tfstate file). The backend file should be in each environment as I list above.

Third, the `*.tfstate` file should be defined in each environment. I have given the sample above in `<env>/backend.conf`

Then we have sever layers to manage terraform stacks, VPC/Network layer, Database/elasticache layers, application layers. So you can group the stack resource accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! But without main.tf for an env what will you run? `main.tf` file for any env will have all modules with source. So `main.tf` for envs will just have list of modules to use (different than other `main.tf` of modules). 
Yes I am using AWS and I want S3 as backend. But there is bug in Terraform that doesn't allow to configure S3 as backend and during `terraform init` it says `InvalidClientTokenId` despite being root user.

Comment: please make sure you set AWS API key properly (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/)

Comment: Seriously sir? How do you think I reached at this point without setting AWS API keys properly? Please refer Terraform Git for Open issues. I asked for work around if any.
(https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/663#issuecomment-334495683)

Comment: @arman K, I went through the link you provided. I think that's something new problem which is not related the question you ask in first place. and you have ticket followed in github, that's the best place for you new problem.  Do you still have any questions for your design issue you raised for?

Comment: no sir. The design you proposed can be modified here and there for my requirement. So that looks fine. Thanks for the help!